# In PHP, if I have domain forwarding, how can I get the domain name that refers the traffic?

Tags: php

I have three domain names.  For convenience, let's call them, mainSite.com, Site1.com, and Site2.com.  Site1.com and Site2.com are set up as domain forwarding to go to mainSite.com.  Using PHP, on mainSite.com, is there a way to tell whether people come to the site by going through Site1.com or Site2.com?  Would `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, if populated, give me that information?

Comment: From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) *"The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted."* So yes, if it is set it will give you that info. It is easily tested.